# Proving that a curve is closed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

Consider the $2$-nd order dynamic system defined as:

$\dot{x}_1=x_2, \qquad\dot{x}_2=-g(x_1)$

where $g$ is a continuously differentiable function and $\xi\cdot g(\xi)>0, \forall \xi \in (-a,a),$ with $a$ being a known positive scalar. Defining the following energy function:

$V(x)=\frac{1}{2}x_2^2 + \int_{0}^{x_1}g(\xi) d\xi$

Is it true that, for sufficiently small $||x(0)||$, every solution is periodic?

(We can easily show that $\dot{V}(x)=0$ over any phase trajectory, namely $V(x)=constant$. However, before analysing whether a solution is periodic, I do not know how to show that the curve $V(x)=constant$ is closed).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you do it when $g(x)=x$? The general case works similar in a neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: By using Taylor's theorem, I have tried expanding the function g(z) in its first-order expression around the origin, assuming ||x(0)||<a, but I am still stuck :(

Comment: You are thinking too complicated. You just need to show that the solution is bounded in both directions.